# Manually switch carriers Project Fi

Tags: carriers, nexus, project-fi

I have heard that you can manually switch carriers when using Project Fi. How do I go about this? What is the easiest way?

**Edit:** Is there an app that does this too?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can easily manually switch carriers in Project Fi:

Head into the Phone Dialer app that came with your Nexus phone, then type in these dialer codes to manually switch carrier:

- Sprint = *#*#FISPR#*#*
- T-Mobile = *#*#FITMO#*#*
- US Cellular = *#*#FIDAN#*#*
- Auto = *#*#FIAUTO#*#*

You can also download the [Fi Info](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mbmc.fiinfo&hl=en) app, which automates the process a bit with a widget (I use it all the time).

[Source and more info.](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/project-fi/IkOy8ZGNyPk;context-place=topicsearchin/project-fi/category$3Aservice-and-coverage)

Answer (score 2):

[Singal Spy](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.novvia.fispy) is the app that I use to do this.
It also shows you at a glance what network you are currently connected to:
[image]

Comment: Thanks! This works too, just as well as Fi Info (which also has that notification thing).